# Pandas pivot_table re-arrage columns in proper hierarchy

Tags: pandas

After doing some logn magic with pivot tables (changing levels of columns, dropping some levels, merging several pivot_tables) I ended up with this presentation of column levels in the final df:

```
P1  P2  P1  P2 - level 0
F1  F1  F2  F2 - level 1
```

I am lost as to why it is represented in this way as I would expect a proper hierarchical ordering taking into account multilevel structure, e.g.

```
P1  P1  P2  P2
F1  F2  F1  F2
```

How do I re-set the columns in the proper hierarchical way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you need sort it by first level with [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html):

```
df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
```

Sample:

```
np.random.seed(123)
cols = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([['P1','P2','P1', 'P2'],['F1','F1','F2','F2']])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(4,4)), columns=cols)
print (df)
  P1 P2 P1 P2
  F1 F1 F2 F2
0  2  2  6  1
1  3  9  6  1
2  0  1  9  0
3  0  9  3  4

df = df.sort_index(axis=1, level=0)
print (df)
  P1    P2   
  F1 F2 F1 F2
0  2  6  2  1
1  3  6  9  1
2  0  9  1  0
3  0  3  9  4
```